# Angular JWT Token refresh

Tags: angular, .net-core, jwt

I have this angular application with .Net Core backend, using JWT authentication tokens. Everything is working well, except for this one thing: When login happens, a button is supposed to appear (only whith the presence of the JWT in the local storage) immediately...but it doesn't! Only when I refresh the page the button appears in the navbar! Is there anyway I can resolve this? Thanks in advance!

This is the component where I am using the variable "isLoggedIn" so the button is displayed, or not:
**top-bar.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z10 toolbar-style">
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">
        <img class="top-bar-logo" src="assets/Images/DocShareAppLogo.png" alt="DocShareApp-Automobile">
    </a>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <div class="spaceInButtons" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
        <mat-menu #appAccountMenu="matMenu">
            <button routerLink="personalInfo" mat-menu-item>Personal Info</button>
        </mat-menu>

        <a mat-raised-button class="account-button-color" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appAccountMenu">
            My Account
        </a>
    </div>
    <mat-menu #appFabAccount="matMenu">
        <button routerLink="registerLogin" mat-menu-item>Register/Login</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <a mat-fab class="account-button-color" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appFabAccount">
        <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
    </a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

**top-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.css']
})
export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }

}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  readonly rootURL = 'https://localhost:5001/';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private toastr: ToastrService, private router: Router) { }

  postLogin(formModel: FormGroup, formDirective: FormGroupDirective){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.rootURL + 'Users/login', formModel).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        if (response.succeeded)
        formModel.reset();
        formDirective.resetForm();
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
        //localStorage.removeItem('token');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        this.toastr.success('You have been logged in', response.message, { positionClass: 'toast-top-right' } )
      },
      errorResponse => {
       this.toastr.error(errorResponse.error.message, 'Login unsuccessful', { positionClass: 'toast-top-right' });
        }
    );  
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean{
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error prone code.

Comment: I posted the service class, tell me if you need the html or anything else

Comment: Posting code as images makes it hard to reproduce. A much better version would be a minimal working example (for eg. using Stackblitz). And yes, it isn't clear without the template.

Comment: is your `isAuthenticated()` check happening before the `postLogin()` check?  Post your template code!

Comment: The isAuthenticated() is called so a check-up is made to see if the token is in the local storage(browser), if it is, its a proof that the user's postLogin() was successful(because the server returned a jwt), therefore, the button on the navbar will appear!

Comment: Can you verify that the JWT is actually being stored in your local storage once you've logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use object to inform your component to update the template after login success

**auth.service.ts**

```
loginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

setLogin(status) {
  this.loginSubject.next(status);
}
```

then use setLogin(true) after you set this.toastr.success / this.toastr.error

**top-bar.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.authService.loginSubject.subscribe(
    status => this.isLoggedIn = status
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! After researching a bit about the BehaviorSubject, thhis makes perfect sense! Cheers!

Comment: haha thanks i just learn it too...